# Google API Javascript, How to get the current location on IP-Address and on live site?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-api

I wrote a code that works fine in JSFiddle, also at localhost, it is working fine. But when I move it to IP or on live site of Godaddy domain, it shows blank page! why?
Please Help me to get out of this problem. As I do google and spent a lot of time but not get any solution. Problem is with IP address and live server website. Please give me a solution if you know about this problem.

Here is the code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script  src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB3_ve60J0oE7IXz-LTuE0SqaWI8MWP9uQ&callback=requestPosition" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function setText(val, e) {
 document.getElementById(e).value = val;
 }
 function insertText(val, e) {
 document.getElementById(e).value += val;
 }

 var nav = null; 
 function requestPosition() {
  if (nav == null) {
  nav = window.navigator;
  }
 if (nav != null) {
  var geoloc = nav.geolocation;
  if (geoloc != null) {
      geoloc.getCurrentPosition(successCallback);
  }
  else {
      alert("geolocation not supported");
   }
  }
  else {
  alert("Navigator not found");
     }
 }
 function successCallback(position)
 {
  setText(position.coords.latitude, "latitude");
   setText(position.coords.longitude, "longitude");
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
   position.coords.longitude);
   var myOptions = {
   zoom: 8,
   center: latlng,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map124"), myOptions);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker
   (
   {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
    position.coords.longitude),
     map: map,
     title: 'Click me'
     }
     );
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <label for="latitude">Latitude: </label><input id="latitude" /> <br />
   <label for="longitude">Longitude: </label><input id="longitude" /> <br />
  <input type="button" onclick="requestPosition()" value="Get Latitude and Longitude"  /> 
   <div id="map124" style="width:400px;height:400px">
            </div>

   </body>    
   </html>
```

Comment: If it shows a blank page, it's probably not an issue with your geolocation code. Probably something else is causing that issue.

Comment: @Terry i think you are right. Problem is with Google API key or some thing else.

Comment: @Terry i am also facing the same issue, and i know its not the code issue. Its something else. Do you know about this or not?

Comment: @MMG if you resolved with it please tell

Comment: Is your site served over HTTPS:?

Comment: @geocodezip i changed the javascripts links like this <script  src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB3_ve60J0oE7IXz-LTuE0SqaWI8MWP9uQ&callback=requestPosition" ></script>

Comment: @geocodezip check the updated code now

Comment: you didn't answer my question.  Geolocation only works when the page is served over https: on modern browsers.

Comment: @geocodezip you were right. I made a SSL cetificate at domain and now it works fine.